# Static list item inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

So,

I am rendering a basic list using ngRepeat, but need the first `<li>` to be static content, rather than being generated from the data array:

e.g.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items">
  <li>This is text from the template and will always be the same.</li>
  <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I've also looked at using `ng-repeat-start`, but just can't quite get to a solution.

Comment: move your ng-repeat from ul to the second li element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a common misconception that people want to use `ng-repeat` on the parent element, when in fact you use it on the actual elements that do the repeating.

You just need to change it to:

```
<ul>
  <li>This is text from the template and will always be the same.</li>
  <li  ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved and misconception corrected :)

Comment: now that I think about it your repeater was probably working...except it was creating numerous `<ul>` with a single child before